# Execute task after another

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Recently I started developing for iOS and faced problem which is maybe obvious for you but I couldn't figure it out by myself. 
What I'm trying to do is to execute task after another one, using multithreading provided by GCD.

This is my code for fetching JSON (put in class with singleton)
CategoriesStore

```
- (instancetype)initPrivate {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [self sessionConf];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *getCategories =
        [self.session dataTaskWithURL:categoriesURL
                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                        NSURLResponse *response,
                                        NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"error - %@",error.localizedDescription);
                        }

                        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

                        if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
                            NSError *jsonError;

                            NSArray *json =
                            [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                              error:&jsonError];
                            if (!jsonError) {
                                _allCategories = json;
                                NSLog(@"allcategories - %@",_allCategories);
                            }
                        }
        }];

        [getCategories resume];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then in ViewController I execute

```
- (void)fetchCategories {
    NSLog(@"before");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
            CategoriesStore *categories = [CategoriesStore sharedStore];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            _allDirectories = categories.allCategories;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"after");
        });
    });
}
```

-fetchCategories is executed in viewDidAppear. The result is usually **before, after** and then **JSON**. Obviously what I want to get is **before, json after**.

I also tried to do this with dispatch_group_notify but didn't workd.

How can I get it working? Why it doesn't wait for first task to be finished?
Thank's for any help! 
Regards, Adrian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to define a dedicated method in `CategoriesStore` that fetches data from remote server and takes callback as an argument:

```
- (void)fetchDataWithCallback:(void(^)(NSArray *allCategories, NSError* error))callback
{

    NSURLSessionDataTask *getCategories =
        [self.session dataTaskWithURL:categoriesURL
                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                        NSURLResponse *response,
                                        NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"error - %@",error.localizedDescription);
                            callback(nil, error);
                            return;
                        }

                        NSError *jsonError = nil;

                        NSArray *json =
                        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error:&jsonError];
                        if (!jsonError) {
                            _allCategories = json;
                            NSLog(@"allcategories - %@",_allCategories);
                            callback(_allCategories, nil);
                        } else {
                            callback(nil, jsonError);
                        }
        }];

        [getCategories resume];
}
```

And you can use it in your `ViewController`:

```
- (void)fetchCategories {
    [[CategoriesStore sharedStore] fetchDataWithCallback:^(NSArray *allCategories, NSError* error) {
        if (error) {
            // handle error here
        } else {
            _allDirectories = allCategories;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }]
}
```

In this way you will reload your table view after data loading & parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the reload data so you may do something like this, another option if you don't want to wait for the whole block and just for the fetch is to use a custom [NSLock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/)

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    _allDirectories = categories.allCategories;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
NSLog(@"after");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used method suggested by @sgl0v, although it wasn't solution I expected. 
Another way to do this is by using notification center and listening for event to occur.